# How to use $.ajax function properly?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know how to run $.ajax properly. I usually make all xmlHTTP objects manually using javascript and then use jQuery wherever required. So please help me use this function properly in jQuery.

### HTML

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" onSubmit="return login()" >
                <input type="text" name="eMailTxt" id="eMailTxt" placeholder="Email Address" />
                <input type="password" name="passWordTxt" id="passWordTxt" placeholder="password" />
                <br />
                <p><!--wanna show password does not match here--></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitBtn" class="Btn" />
            </form>
```

### JQuery Ajax

```
function login()
{
    $email = $("#eMailTxt").val();
    $pass = $("#passWordTxt").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'loginCheck.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{q:$email,s:$pass},
        success:function(response){
            $("#loginForm p").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            return false; //is this the correct way to do it?
        }
    });
    return true; //not really sure about this
}
```

### PHP MySQL

```
$q=$_POST["q"];
    $s=$_POST["s"];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","SocialNetwork");
    $check="SELECT PassWord FROM people WHERE EMAIL = '".$q."'";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    if ($s != $result)
    {
        echo "Password does not match";
    }
```

Comment: success:function(response){
     $("#loginForm p").html(response.d); 
}

Comment: try to print console.log(response);, then verify the out put on developer tools of browser

Answer (score 1):

jQuery object doesn't have a property `innerHTML` which is used on DOM element. Use method `html()` instead:

```
$("#loginForm p").html(response);
```

Or you could refer to DOM element like that:

```
$("#loginForm p")[0].innerHTML = response; // equivalent to .get(0)
```

Be aware as ajax is async by default, your login function here will always return true.

BTW, response here corresponds to the returned value from server, not the jqXHR object (xhr object wrapped inside a jquery object).

**UPDATE**

```
function login(form)
{
    $email = $("#eMailTxt").val();
    $pass = $("#passWordTxt").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'loginCheck.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{q:$email,s:$pass},
        success:function(response){
            if(response === "Password does not match") {
               $("#loginForm p").html(response);
               return false;
            }
            //if password match, submit form
            form.submit();
        }
    });
    //we always return false here to avoid form submiting before ajax request is done
    return false; 
}
```

In HTML:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" onSubmit="return login(this)" >
```

Comment: It will always return true? I don't want it to return true if password does not match.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" class="js-my-form">
                <input type="text" name="record[email]" id="eMailTxt" placeholder="Email Address" />
                <input type="password" name="record[password]" id="passWordTxt" placeholder="password" />
                <br />
                <p><!--wanna show password does not match here--></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitBtn" class="Btn" />
            </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-my-form').submit(function () {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var methodType = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: methodType,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
               //Maybe Some Ajax Loader
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // success
            },
            error: function (errorResponse) {}
        });

        return false; //Send form async
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['record']) {
//Your PHP Code
} else {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // Trow Error for JS
echo 'invalid data';
}
```

Comment: So, if user enter a wrong password, a 404 error is thrown? Or i missing something?!

Comment: No in this case PHP will send error if your form data is incorrect.

Idea with header("HTTP/1.0 {Error_code} Not Found"); // Trow Error for JS

To throw errors to JS.

Comment: Ok, i get it but you have a typo in your PHP code: `if (isset($_POST['record'>>]<< )`

Comment: Mistake must be : if (isset($_POST['record'])

Comment: if ($_POST['record']['password'] == $database['password') {
//Success
} else {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // Trow Error for JS
echo 'invalid password';
}

Answer (score 0):

Ajax success call back contains only data (you are confused with the compete function of ajax or pure javascript xmlhttp request)
therefore

```
    success:function(response){
     $("#loginForm p").html(response); 
}
```

Also seeing your query you are susceptible to sql injection